# Intrinsic function, cannot be defined (C)

Tags: c, visual-studio, intrinsics

I implemented a function called abs(). I get this error:

> Intrinsic function, cannot be defined

What have I done wrong?
I'm using Visual Studio 2005.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Intrinsic function, cannot be defined

In this case, [intrinsic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function) means that the compiler *already* has an implementation of a function called `abs`, and which you cannot redefine.

Solution? Change **your** function's name to something else, `snakile_abs` for example.

Check the MSDN documentation on the [`abs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw1ee768.aspx) function for more information.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not being in a header or not.

The problem is that intrinsic functions, i.e., functions that the compiler recognizes and implements itself, generally with optimizations that wouldn't be available in C code alone, cannot be defined.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give an example? What do you mean by "compiler... implements itself"? What if I need to use that abs() function?

Comment: @sna You mean you want to use an abs function *different* from the one in the standard c library?... just name it something else...

Answer (score 0):

The names of all mathematical functions (see math.h)

The names of all mathematical functions prefixed by 'f' or 'l'.

Are reserved for the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Defining `static int abs(int x) { ... }` should be legal, but simply `int abs(int x) { ... }` has undefined behavior, and thus one reasonable thing a compile could do is issue an error.

Comment: Some header may still have `#define abs __builtin_magic_abs` orthe like. Since the preprocessor sees the text first, you still end up trying to define `static int __buildin_magic_abs(int x){...}`. Since abs() is a name defined in the C standard library, it is likely to be unwise (and certainly not portable) to attempt to replace it by name.

Comment: As long as you don't `#include` any header that defines `abs` or `#undef` it before defining your own version, the Standard specifically allows you to replace it with a `static` function. Replacing the `extern` version is undefined behavior, however.